# Downloading Revit Models with Links

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am using Forge to download Revit models through this API:

```
GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName
```

If I try to download a Revit model that contains link documents, I only get one single Revit model (the root file) and none of the linked documents would be downloaded. But if I download the same model directly from BIM 360, it is downloaded as a zip file that contains all the links. How can I get the same behavior through the Forge API?

P.S. I am pretty sure I used to get the proper behavior from Forge API as well, so this might be a regression.

Comment: How did you link your RVTs together, [upload linked files or by Forge API](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files), or C4R or Revit Could Model? Maybe check

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/

Answer (score 1):

The OSS part of the Forge Data Management API is a simple "object storage service", so it doesn't know about any potential references between files. It's actually a feature of the BIM 360 product that it can read the "main" Revit file, retrieve all references from it, and bundle them all together into a ZIP file.

You might however be able to retrieve the references yourself as well, using one of the following Forge APIs:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-refs-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-relationships-links-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-relationships-refs-GET/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to make sure that you have created and linked the files in the proper way, which you probably have, but just to make sure check [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Collaboration-for-Revit-Local-links-not-visible-on-the-cloud.html).

As Petr Broz mentioned, it is not possible to get a bundle containing all linked files using the forge API. However, you can use

1. `{{FORGE_HOST}}/data/v1/projects/:project/folders/:folder/contents` [(docs)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) to get the folder contents of the BIM360 folder. This will give you a tip version id (latest version id) of the file. Look for `relationships.tip.data.id` of the file you want to download.
2. With this version ID, query `{{FORGE_HOST}}/data/v1/projects/:project/versions/:version/relationships/refs` [(docs)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/). The data field should contain an array with all incoming and outgoing links. Look for `meta.direction` to see if it is incoming or outgoing.

This way you can gather all linked versions.